# S1 equivariant forms

Tags: differential-geometry, equivariant-cohomology, differential-forms

I was reading the article ``[Equivariant cohomology](https://www.ams.org/notices/201103/rtx110300423p.pdf)'' by L.W. Tu. In page 3 (on page 425) he describes any $S^1$ equivariant 2n form on a compact, oriented smooth manifold M is given by $\alpha = \omega_{2n} +\cdots + \omega_0 u^n$. Where $u \in H^{*}_{S^1}(pt; \mathbb{R})$ and $\omega_{2j}$ is an $S^1$-invariant 2j form on $M$.

$\underline{Ques-1}$ :

Let's take a $S^1$ equivariant 2 form $\alpha_2 = \omega_2 + \omega_0 u $ on M, then neively one should get a $S^1$ equivariant 3 form by $d_g(\alpha_2) = d_g(\omega_2 + \omega_0 u)$, where $\omega_2$ is a $S^1$ invariant 2 form, $\omega_0$ is a $S^1$ invariant smooth function and $d_g$ the equivariant exterior derivative, defined by $d_g(\alpha)(X)=(d + i_{X^{\#}})(\alpha(X))$.

But $d_g(\alpha_2) = d\omega_2$ + second term involving contraction of a zero form. Then how it's an equivariant 3 form? Can anyone please help me with the above computation so that I can understand what is going on!

$\underline{Ques-2}$ :

Since M can be embedded in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ (Whitney embedding theorem) so I am curious to know that can we somehow think of (maybe extension is a correct word to use) the above $S^1$ equivariant 2 form as an $S^1$ equivariant 2 form in some $\mathbb{R}^n$?

If it is possible, it should be explicitly expressed in terms of some $f dx \wedge dy + g  dy \wedge dx$ for some f and g, something like this I guess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not downvote.. I think question can be made better... It is not clear what is your background, in the sense what all can people assume to give answer for you....  I am not able to make sense of, for example, $d_g(\alpha_2)=d_g(\alpha_2)(\omega_2+\omega_0u)$.. What does that mean?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79041/cartan-weil-model-for-equivariant-cohomology and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86419/equivariant-differential-forms might be of some help for  you

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik I am sorry I should have clarified what is $\alpha_2$. Now I have edited.

Comment: Even I am trying to understand this (seriously) for the first time... :) I can not help you much :) Have you consulted any book on equivariant forms?

Comment: @ Praphulla Koushik, Sure  Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators  you will find it here https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540200628

Comment: As far as I understand, your questions are as follows :

 1. If it is true (as mentioned in Tu's article) that every $S^1$-equivariant $2n$-form $\alpha$ on  a (nice) manifold $M$ is (a polynomial) of the form $$\omega_{2n}+\omega_{2n-2}u+\omega_{2n-4}u^2+\cdots +\omega_0u^n$$ then, if I take an "equivariant $2$-form" $\alpha=\omega_2+\omega_0u$ and take the "equivariant derivative $d_g$", it is not clear why $d_g(\alpha)$ is "an equivariant $3$-form" on $M$. Question is, what do you think a "equivariant $3$-form" should look like?

Comment: 2.  Using an embedding of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, can we extend an "equivariant form on $M$" to get an "equivariant $G$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$".. What I do not understand how do you make sense of equivariant form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ if it is not clear whether action of $G$ on $M$ can be extended to action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$... I tried to read the notion of equivariant form on a manifold but I do not think I understand the definition... If you have time, please write what it means to say an equivariant $G$ form on a manifold $M$ if I have an action of $G$ on $M$...

Comment: Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQZfZKhc0kiCevQ-_jlplD1ir2N4-eGR3

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your question 1:

Let's first clarify that when you write an $S^1$-equivariant $2n$-form as $\alpha=\omega_{2n}+\dots+\omega_0u^n$, you are fixing a basis $e_1$ for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\mathrm{Lie}(\mathbb{S}^1)\cong\mathbb{R}$ and taking $u=e_1^*$, the dual covector, and the powers $u^n$ mean tensor powers $u\otimes\dots\otimes u$. It is good to also recall that the canonical grading of the Cartan complex counts the polynomial degree doubled (so in fact each term in $\alpha$ is an equivariant $2n$-form). This makes $d_{\mathfrak{g}}$ into a degree-$1$ derivation, so indeed $d_{\mathfrak{g}}\alpha$ is an equivariant $(2n+1)$-form, as you guessed. Finally, recall that if $\omega$ is invariant, then so are $d\omega$ and $i_{x^\#}\omega$.

Instead of considering the equivariant $2$-form $\alpha_2=\omega_2+\omega_0u$, let us take an equivariant $4$-form $\alpha_4=\omega_4+\omega_2u+\omega_0u^2$, so that we have to work with the terms involving $i_{X^\#}$ when we take $d_{\mathfrak{g}}$ (which all vanish for $\alpha_2$). Notice that for $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ we have $X=u(X)e_1$, where $u(X)$ is the coordinate of $X$ in the basis $\{e_1\}$. Hence
$$\alpha_4(X)=(\omega_4+\omega_2u+\omega_0u^2)X=\omega_4+u(X)\omega_2+u(X)^2\omega_0.$$
We also have $i_{X^\#}=u(X)i_{e_1^\#}$ (let's write $i_1:=i_{e_1^\#}$ for simplicity). Then
\begin{align*}d_{\mathfrak{g}}\alpha(X) & = d(\alpha(X))+i_{X^\#}(\alpha(X))\\
 & = d[\omega_4+u(X)\omega_2+u(X)^2\omega_0]+i_{X^\#}[\omega_4+u(X)\omega_2+u(X)^2\omega_0]\\
 & = d\omega_4+u(X)d\omega_2+u(X)^2d\omega_0+u(X)i_1\omega_4+u(X)^2i_1\omega_2\\
& = d\omega_4+u(X)[d\omega_2+i_1\omega_4]+u(X)^2[d\omega_0+i_1\omega_2]\\
 & = [d\omega_4+(d\omega_2+i_1\omega_4)u+(d\omega_0+i_1\omega_2)u^2](X).\end{align*}
That is, $d_{\mathfrak{g}}\alpha=d\omega_4+(d\omega_2+i_1\omega_4)u+(d\omega_0+i_1\omega_2)u^2$. Notice that \begin{align*}
\mathrm{deg}(d\omega_4) & =5,\\
\mathrm{deg}((d\omega_2+i_1\omega_4)u)  =\mathrm{deg}(d\omega_2+i_1\omega_4)+\mathrm{deg}(u)=3+2 & =5,\\
\mathrm{deg}((d\omega_0+i_1\omega_2)u^2) =\mathrm{deg}(d\omega_0+i_1\omega_2)+\mathrm{deg}(u^2)=1+4 & =5.
\end{align*}
Hence $d_{\mathfrak{g}}\alpha$ is in fact an equivariant $5$-form.

Concerning your question 2, @Praphulla Koushik already made a good point in the comments: even if you could extend the $\mathbb{S}^1$-action to the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$, this would be in general a very weird action, certainly not linear. This would not help with the calculations, if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Fantastic!! An excellent answer which I was looking for.  Earlier I was concerned with the contraction term. Your answer made that point crystal clear.

Comment: Concerning 2nd question, since a differential form in R^n are extremely explicit (looks like $f_1 df_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge df_{n+1}$ where $f_1, \cdots, f_n$ are global functions). So I thought maybe if I can extend (somehow) a $S^1$ equivariant 2 form in M into a $S^1$ equivariant 2 form in some $R^n$ then the resulting extended 2-form may looks simpler.